# unable to get high quality bitmap from camera

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, camera

i need to get captured picture from camera but it seem this code:

```
Intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
```

stops activity from getting to `onActivityResult` and throw an exception like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity
```

thats what i figured out from 5 hours searching.

this is my code:
intent

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Files");
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String mImageName = "MI_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
filePath = imageUri.getPath();
Log.e("000", filePath + " :|");
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
```

at Log line i get the path but when i press save on camera app i get error and a null `filePath`

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
appPanel.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

this code is fine but returns a low quality image:

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

**Finally i found the solution:**

we must save the path at `onSaveInstanceState` as below:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

CharSequence userText = CapturedPath;
outState.putCharSequence("savedText", userText);
}
```

and bring it back on `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

CapturedPath =savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedText").toString();

//Load bitamp from here:
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(CapturedPath);
appPanel.setBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem and device camera app sometimes doesn't return any data onActivityResult(). 
It's especially OS dependencies.

My gist is below. hope this can help you a little.

[CameraManager](https://gist.github.com/neonankiti/6c12da0c2fc8bc09adfb87e93d634192)

Comment: i find a solution describe in my post

Comment: I forgot to put the new support lib for exifInterface.
This would handle all the orientatino properly for all devices and OS. 
No problems so far. Please check this out. 

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html

Answer (score -1):

After some research i found this

if you've got the camera object, try:

```
android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
android.hardware.Camera.Size size = parameters.getPictureSize();


int height = size.height;
int width = size.width;
```

Resolution refers to the number of pixels in an image. Resolution is sometimes identified by the width and height of the image as well as the total number of pixels in the image. For example, an image that is 2048 pixels wide and 1536 pixels high (2048X1536) contains (multiply) 3,145,728 pixels (or 3.1 Megapixels).  You could call it a 2048X1536 or a 3.1 Megapixel image.  As the megapixels in the pickup device in your camera increase so does the possible maximum size image you can produce.  This means that a 5 megapixel camera is capable of capturing a larger image than a 3 megapixel camera.

Example:  1936 x 1552 / 1024000 = 3 Mega Pixels

Comment: how can i use that as answer?